# ОсвЕдомить или осведомИть ?

Tags: ударение

Большой толковый словарь дает это слово с ударением на последнем слове, а орфографический словарь - на втором. Чему же верить?

Прочитал о том, что на ЕГЭ используют ограниченный список слов с ударением. Интересно, где посмотреть этот список. Лариса, Вы не посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Себе. 
В таких случаях надо верить орфоэпическим словарям (я предпочитаю Аванесова, но у меня старый), в частности - словарям для дикторов радио и телевиденья. Последние можно считать нормативным эталоном, одна беда: они очень редко переиздаются и обычно недоступны простым смертным.

В данном случае БТС - более авторитетный источник по "статусу", но Лопатин, похоже, прав. Мне "осведомИть" никогда не нравилось.

Беда, что от отсутствия единства в головах академиков страдают дети. Особенно - на ЕГЭ.

~~~~~

Посмотрел. В Аванесове 1989 г.: освЕдомить; осведомИть - не рекомендуется. 
И если верить [В.В. Лопатину](http://www.gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/norma/28_367), вариант осведомИть как нормативный появился впервые в словаре «Давайте говорить правильно» Л. Вербицкой и др., вызвавшем огромное количество споров и нареканий (как и почти всё, из-под пера [Людмилы Алексеевны](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F,_%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) вышедшее - тут у них с [Владимиром Владимировичем](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) полный паритет).

Comment: На ЕГЭ от ударений никто не страдает. Там уже три года как ограниченный список слов в открытом доступе.

Comment: Ну слава-тебе-господи!  
Но вообще-то я в более широком смысле.

Answer (score 0):

А здравый смысл уже не является авторитетным источником?
Для чего следовать взаимоисключающим правилам постановки ударений:
1. В глаголах на -ить, ударение падает на последний слог. Тут же нелепое исключение: кроме опОшлить, освЕдомить;
2. В отглагольных существительных СОХРАНЯЕТСЯ ударение глагола. Без исключений.
освЕдомить - освЕдомление  -ОсвЕдомитель, опОшлить - опОшление - опОшлитель?

Comment: 0. Нет, не является. 1. не обязательно 2. не всегда.